# difference between Magento standard API and simple php file on the root

Tags: magento

difference between create an api using magento 
standards and create a php file in the root and 
get and send response using simple php code.

1. is there any security reason we use magento standards ?
2. any difference in speed of response ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there any security reason we use magento standards ?

The standard Magento APIs have been tested significantly more than anything that has yet to be written, so, yes, in terms of security, it's better to avoid writing something custom.

> any difference in speed of response ?

Yes, Magento's SOAP APIs are terribly slow. Haven't done much testing with the newer REST API, so I'm not sure if that's any faster.

A third, somewhat obvious, point is that Magento's APIs are already written and can be used on any site out of the box (with minimal configuration). Writing a custom API means that it has to be installed on the site before it can be used.

Also, thinking outside of the box, sometimes it's beneficial to reverse the process. Instead of Foo talking to Magento, let Magento talk to Foo. Of course, this depends on what you're doing, but sometimes this is a much better way of implementing a form of communication between Magento and another system.